# how to get click button event of dynamically created button C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code which generates buttons dynamically

```
Button txt = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(txt);
txt.Top = cleft * 40;
txt.Name = "txt_" + cb;
txt.Size = new Size(200, 16);
txt.Left = 150;
```

But I cannot think how to generate its click event.

Comment: I would do a quick google search on how to create `Delegates` you could also google how to get at an object from the `(send)` object

Comment: `txt.Click += (sender, e) => {/* your code here */};`

Comment: @YvetteColomb Except I don't think that is the right duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't mean "how to generate", but rather how to handle. Since you have a reference to your dynamic button, just add an event handler:

```
txt.Click += new EventHandler(eventHandlerFunction);
```

Or use a lambda:

```
txt.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => ...;
```

Comment: Yess that is I meant!